# How do I create a Facebook login in unity using Firebase?

Tags: c#, android, firebase, authentication, unity-game-engine

So I've tried to use Firebase for unity and create a Facebook login for my project.

I've followed every instructions in firebase documentation and Facebook developer including importing SDK's into my projects and adding `appID` keyhashes in the Facebook login alone works fine but once I tried to send it into Firebase to keep login informations I kept getting exceptions.

**Here is my code:**

```
using System.Collections;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using UnityEngine;
using Facebook.Unity;

public class facebookLogin : MonoBehaviour {

// Use this for initialization
void Awake()
        {
        if (!FB.IsInitialized)
            {
                // Initialize the Facebook SDK
                FB.Init(InitCallback, OnHideUnity);
            }
            else
            {
                // Already initialized, signal an app activation App Event
                FB.ActivateApp();
            }
        }
        private void InitCallback()
        {
            if (FB.IsInitialized)
            {
                // Signal an app activation App Event
                FB.ActivateApp();
                // Continue with Facebook SDK
                // ...
            }
            else
            {
                Debug.Log("Failed to Initialize the Facebook SDK");
            }
        }

        private void OnHideUnity(bool isGameShown)
        {
            if (!isGameShown)
            {
                // Pause the game - we will need to hide
                Time.timeScale = 0;
            }
            else
            {
                // Resume the game - we're getting focus again
                Time.timeScale = 1;
            }
        }
        public void FBlogin()
        {
            List<string> permissions = new List<string>();
            permissions.Add("public_profile");
            permissions.Add("email");
            permissions.Add("user_friends");
            FB.LogInWithReadPermissions(permissions, AuthCallback);
        }
        private void AuthCallback(ILoginResult result)
        {
            if (FB.IsLoggedIn)
            {
                Firebase.Auth.FirebaseAuth auth = 
Firebase.Auth.FirebaseAuth.DefaultInstance;
                List<string> permissions = new List<string>();

                // AccessToken class will have session details
                var aToken = Facebook.Unity.AccessToken.CurrentAccessToken;
                // Print current access token's User ID
                Debug.Log(aToken.TokenString);
                Debug.Log(aToken.UserId);


                Firebase.Auth.Credential credential =

Firebase.Auth.FacebookAuthProvider.GetCredential(aToken.TokenString);
                auth.SignInWithCredentialAsync(credential).ContinueWith(task 
=> {
                    if (task.IsCanceled)
                    {
                        Debug.LogError("SignInWithCredentialAsync was 
canceled.");
                        return;
                    }
                    if (task.IsFaulted)
                    {
                        Debug.LogError("SignInWithCredentialAsync encountered 
an error: " + task.Exception);
                        return;
                    }

                    Firebase.Auth.FirebaseUser newUser = task.Result;
                    Debug.LogFormat("User signed in successfully: {0} ({1})",
                        newUser.DisplayName, newUser.UserId);
                });
                // Print current access token's granted permissions
                //foreach(string perms in aToken.Permissions)
                //{
                // Debug.Log(perms);
                //}
            }
            else
            {
                Debug.Log("User cancelled login");
            }
        }
    }
```

**And here my exceptions:**

```
SignInWithCredentialAsync encountered an error: System.AggregateException: Exception of type 'System.AggregateException' was thrown.
-----------------
Firebase.FirebaseException: An account already exists with the same email address but different sign-in credentials. Sign in using a provider associated with this email address.

UnityEngine.Debug:LogError(Object)
facebookLogin:<AuthCallback>m__0(Task`1) (at Assets/Script/facebookLogin.cs:82)
System.Threading.Tasks.TaskCompletionSource`1:SetException(AggregateException)
Firebase.Internal.TaskCompletionSourceCompat`1:SetExceptionInternal(TaskCompletionSource`1, AggregateException)
Firebase.Internal.TaskCompletionSourceCompat`1:SetException(TaskCompletionSource`1, AggregateException)
Firebase.Auth.FirebaseAuth:CompleteFirebaseUserTask(Task`1, TaskCompletionSource`1)
Firebase.Auth.<SignInWithCredentialAsync>c__AnonStorey4:<>m__0(Task`1)
System.Threading.Tasks.TaskCompletionSource`1:SetException(Exception)
Firebase.Auth.<GetTask>c__AnonStorey0:<>m__0()
Firebase.Auth.Future_User:SWIG_CompletionDispatcher(Int32)
Firebase.AppUtilPINVOKE:PollCallbacks()
Firebase.AppUtil:PollCallbacks()
Firebase.Platform.FirebaseAppUtils:PollCallbacks()
Firebase.Platform.FirebaseHandler:Update()
Firebase.Platform.FirebaseMonoBehaviour:Update()
```

I have no idea what went wrong. It seems like something is wrong with `SignInWithCredentialAsync` but I have no idea how to fix it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I don't see anything wrong with your code. As the error says, looks like there's another account already registered with the email of the Facebook account you're trying to login with. Does your app allow other login methods?

From Firebase Help:

> You can configure whether users can create multiple accounts that use
>   the same email address, but are linked to different sign-in methods.
>   For example, if you don't allow multiple accounts with the same email
>   address, a user cannot create a new account that signs in using a
>   Google Account with the email address ex@gmail.com if there already is
>   an account that signs in using the email address ex@gmail.com and a
>   password.

Link: https://support.google.com/firebase/answer/6400716?hl=en

You can fix this in your Firebase console. In `Authentication > Sign-in Method`, scroll down and you will see the section *"Multiple accounts per email address"*. Allow it and the error should be fixed.